# Distinguish between two VPC Endpoints calling my VPC Endpoint Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpc-endpoint

I have a VPC Endpoint Service exposing a MicroService deployed in a private VPC. There are multiple VPC Endpoints created in other AWS accounts and private VPCs that connect to my VPC Endpoint Service.

Is there a way to tell from with in the MicroSevice which VPC Endpoint called it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use VPC flow log to check traffic flowing through your VPC or subnet level. These VPC flow logs while creating them has to be configured to be send logs to either S3 or CloudWatch logs.